# How can I encrypt the Node-RED email login?

Tags: email, encryption, ibm-cloud, node-red, tls1.2

I'm using Node-RED in IBM's Bluemix. There are nodes to get email in and send email out. However, the email credentials do not seem to be encrypted when sent over the internet. I'm a bit concerned about that. Is there a way to find email receive and email send nodes for Node-RD where they login to the email server using TLS (or SSL)?

Answer (score 2):

If you configure the email nodes to point at SSL/TLS ports then they will connect via a secure channel.

Also I believe that if the mail servers support the STARTTLS command then they will upgrade the connection once connected.

Comment: So, if I'm using gmail, how would I know what port to use for the SSL/TLS ports? I found this link below, so would I use

Comment: So, if I'm using gmail, how would I know what port to use for the SSL/TLS ports? I found this link below, so would I use smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465 or 587 for eMail (out) node and use imap.gmail.com
Port: 993 for the eMail-In node in Node-RED? https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/IWiwVluINfs

Comment: You need to consult the doc for your email provider you are using, but I think gmail only supports secure ports